# Não consigo capturar dados de JSON!

Tags: php, json

Galera, tenho um `json` aqui, e usei o `CURL` para pegá-lo!

Aí dei um `json_decode`, só que, já tentei de tudo para pegar os dados, mas nada dá certo. O que pode estar acontecendo?

Eu tentei pegar só a parte itens do `JSON`, e funciona, pegar todos os dados etc! Mas quando tento pegar apenas o `name`, por exemplo, não aparece nada!

Meu código:

```
<?php 


if (!isset($_GET['nome'])) {


}else {


    $name = $_GET['nome'];

    $ch = curl_init();
    // informar URL e outras funções ao CURL
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.clashofclans.com/v1/clans?name=$name");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Accept: application/json', "authorization: Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiIsImtpZCI6IjI4YTMxOGY3LTAwMDAtYTFlYi03ZmExLTJjNzQzM2M2Y2NhNSJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJzdXBlcmNlbGwiLCJhdWQiOiJzdXBlcmNlbGw6Z2FtZWFwaSIsImp0aSI6IjJiMDU4Zjc1LWUwMmItNDAyNC1hNjAzLTgxODdiNGQ1ODczMiIsImlhdCI6MTQ3NjkzMjA5MSwic3ViIjoiZGV2ZWxvcGVyL2FiYjVkZWU0LWM5ODItMmJiNC01YWY1LWMzOGVhOGEyNjBkMSIsInNjb3BlcyI6WyJjbGFzaCJdLCJsaW1pdHMiOlt7InRpZXIiOiJkZXZlbG9wZXIvc2lsdmVyIiwidHlwZSI6InRocm90dGxpbmcifSx7ImNpZHJzIjpbIjE4NS4yOC4yMC4xNSJdLCJ0eXBlIjoiY2xpZW50In1dfQ.v3HR-l3UE2_oDnDobQuxmwH3HfFkR2wyW3KRRjqo0Pg6QtCqKki1po7GGbLODSMBJHgs1EkYFHyxOZun2t6koA"));
    // Acessar a URL e retornar a saída
    $json = curl_exec($ch);
    // liberar
    curl_close($ch);
    // Imprimir a saída
    $info = json_decode($json, true);

    echo ("Clãs com nome: $name");
    echo ("<br>");
    echo ($info->itens->title);
}
?>
```

Um pedacinho do JSON:

```
{
  "items": [
    {
      "tag": "#Q8PC0JP8",
      "name": "UNIÃO LENDÁRIA",
      "type": "open",
      "location": {
        "id": 32000038,
        "name": "Brazil",
        "isCountry": true,
        "countryCode": "BR"
      },
      "badgeUrls": {
        "small": "https://api-assets.clashofclans.com/badges/70/E75PzYKp5iqzLoCBSKfmURN757zafvXZUL29KhLSFs0.png",
        "large": "https://api-assets.clashofclans.com/badges/512/E75PzYKp5iqzLoCBSKfmURN757zafvXZUL29KhLSFs0.png",
        "medium": "https://api-assets.clashofclans.com/badges/200/E75PzYKp5iqzLoCBSKfmURN757zafvXZUL29KhLSFs0.png"
      },
      "clanLevel": 1,
      "clanPoints": 414,
      "requiredTrophies": 200,
      "warFrequency": "always",
      "warWinStreak": 0,
      "warWins": 1,
      "warTies": 0,
      "warLosses": 2,
      "isWarLogPublic": true,
      "members": 1
    }, //e por aí vai
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Faça o seguinte:

- Por padrão o cURL irá verificar se o certificado do servidor é válido, se a verificação falhar, a conexão falhará, para desativar altere [`CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER`](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER.html) para `false`:

  ```
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
  ```
- `$info = json_decode($json, true)`: Ao indicar o segundo parâmetro como `true` o objeto retornado será convertido num `array` associativo. Para pegar o `name`, faça `$info['items'][0]['name']` e não `$info->itens->title`.

  <kbd>[Ver **DEMO**](http://ideone.com/9mGrye)</kbd>

Comment: e como eu faria para criar um while, e colocar todos os resultados?

Comment: @SampaioLeal Como assim? você diz, colocar todos os valores (e não as chaves) num *array* unidimensional?

Comment: bom n, esse json, é o resultado de uma pesquisa, ou seja, vem vários resultados dentro do 'itens', e quero fazer um loop para mostrar pelo menos 10 resultados, so com o 'name' por exemplo

Comment: @SampaioLeal Seria algo próximo a isso? http://ideone.com/oTamjB

Comment: obrigado funcionou, mas tem como filtrar isso? deixar aparecer apenas 10 ou 20? qualquer coisa crio uma box com scroll

Comment: @SampaioLeal Tem sim, veja essa outra versão com o `for`: http://ideone.com/4VHeXQ